# Scrapy CrawlSpider next page isn't working

Tags: pagination, scrapy

I wanted to scrape all items from each card and the firsr rule is working fine but the second rule meaning pagination rule is not working.
This is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class RealtorListSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'realtor_list'

    allowed_domains = ['www.realtor.com']

    start_urls = ['https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/New-Orleans_LA/pg-1']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@data-testid="component-agentCard"]'), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@aria-label="Go to next page"]'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
        )
        
    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield{
            'name': response.xpath('(//*[@class="jsx-3130164309 profile-Tiltle-main"]/text())[2]').get()
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your element selection in linkextractor, not in rule for pagination. Xpath expression doesn't contain link selection but selection is correct that's why I 've made the pagination in starting url and it's working fine.

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class RealtorListSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'realtor_list'

    allowed_domains = ['www.realtor.com']

    start_urls = ['https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/New-Orleans_LA/pg-'+str(x) +'' for x in range(1,6)]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@data-testid="component-agentCard"]'), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
        )
        
    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield{
            'name': response.xpath('(//*[@class="jsx-3130164309 profile-Tiltle-main"]/text())[2]').get()
                }
```